# how can i use a json output in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to figure out how to get a `json` output in `python`.
here is the url:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false

whose output would be like this

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "origin_addresses": [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada", "Seattle, État de Washington, États-Unis" ],
  "destination_addresses": [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis", "Victoria, BC, Canada" ],
  "rows": [ {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 340110,
        "text": "3 jours 22 heures"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1734542,
        "text": "1 735 km"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 24487,
        "text": "6 heures 48 minutes"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 129324,
        "text": "129 km"
      }
    } ]
  }, {
    "elements": [ {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 288834,
        "text": "3 jours 8 heures"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 1489604,
        "text": "1 490 km"
      }
    }, {
      "status": "OK",
      "duration": {
        "value": 14388,
        "text": "4 heures 0 minutes"
      },
      "distance": {
        "value": 135822,
        "text": "136 km"
      }
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

How can i print this output in python ?
Can anyone help me out ?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean "print this output in Python". Anyway: http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/json.html#module-json

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers agreed the title is misleading - "how to use" and "how to 'print'" are different things

Comment: @JonClements if I am printing it aint I using it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version of Python, importing JSON might not be enough.

If you are running a version of python less than 2.6, you need to install simplejson from your commandline.

> pip install simplejson

After that, just import normally.

```
import simplejson as json
```

The following should work in Python 2.x.  There are a few differences in 3.x, I'll leave that as an exercise for your imagination.

```
try:
    import json
except:
    import simplejson as json
url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&mode=bicycling&language=fr-FR&sensor=false"
contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
json_array = json.loads(contents)
print repr(json_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]')
```

http://docs.python.org/library/json.html